# Can't locate POE/Component/Client/HTTP.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying to run this perl web proxy code [link](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook/Web_Proxy) but I have an error saying that I have HTTP.pm is missing !

the message:

```
Can't locate POE/Component/Client/HTTP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the POE::Component::Client::HTTP module) (@INC contains: /home/res/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.epic.debug /home/res/workspace/perlone/CIDS-dev /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/res/workspace/perlone/CIDS-dev/webproxy.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/res/workspace/perlone/CIDS-dev/webproxy.pl line 7.
```

So, what should I install to run this code.
Thanks,

Comment: How did you install POE?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear in telling you what you need to install.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the Perl module [`POE::Component::Client::HTTP`](http://metacpan.org/module/POE::Component::Client::HTTP). If you have access, try running this from command line:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install POE::Component::Client::HTTP'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [`POE::Component::Client::HTTP`](http://metacpan.org/module/POE::Component::Client::HTTP)